# I have to program a scheduler with timers

Tags: nxp-microcontroller

We are using S12XEA100 microcontroller. We don't have any OS. We have to implement Scheduler and Timer to run some tasks. I dont have any idea where to start and what are the required things to be noted.

Can u please help me out in this

Thanks in Advance,
Harshitha

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not a toomuch time critical, then you can simplify your project as below
1. Initialise a timer to 1mSec or a your required minimum time
2. In the Timer interrupt function, update the required time variables/flags like 2mSec, 5mSec, 1Sec, 15min....etc.
3. Call a function in the while loop eg: scheduler();
4. In the scheduler(), check the time variables & call your corresponding functions or write the line of code according to the time interval